# Vandermonde Determinant and Polynomials in $\Bbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory* textbook, he gives the following exercise:

> Use the Vandermonde determinant to prove that if a polynomial $f(t)$ vanishes for all $t\in\Bbb C$, then all coefficients of $f$ are zero.

He provides a hint of considering $t=1,2,\ldots$, so I set up a system of linear equations for $t=1,2,\ldots,n$. Setting this up in matrix form, since all of the complex numbers chosen are distinct, we have a Vandermonde matrix with nonzero determinant, hence it is invertible, so the system of equations is solvable by multiplying on the left by the inverse of this matrix. Since the solution vector on the right is just the zero vector, this yields the values for each coefficient is zero.

Is this correct and is this what the author was intending? Are there other solutions using the Vandermonde determinant in a way I don't see? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Such a succinct answer. Thanks! -Also, are there other solutions using Vandermonde?